# How to shift the position of tabbed panes

Tags: java, jtabbedpane

I know that when I create an instance of tabbed panes I set the position as such:

```
 jtp = new JTabbedPane(SwingConstants.LEFT)
```

My question is that is it possible to set the position to the left as above, but to shift the starting position a little bit downwards? I do not want the first tab appearing at the very top of the left hand side. I want to leave some empty space. Is that possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a work around for this problem. I did this by creating a "dummy" icon which was basically a square with the same colour as the background colour of the tabbed panes. I then set this icon as the icon for a "dummy" tabbed pane and disabled the tab:

```
jtp.addTab("", dummyIcon, null);
jtp.setEnabledAt(0, false);
```

By resizing the icon I could make the first tabbed pane take up as much space as i wanted since the panes don't have to be the same size. This way The first tab was not clickable and it had a colour similar to the background colour of the panel, so it appeared as if the space was empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can pack your component into **javax.swing.Box** add shift it:

```
jtp.add("Component shifted vertically", shiftVertical(your_component, 5)); // 5 px or more

public static Box shiftVertical(JComponent component, int size){
    Box vBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
    vBox.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(size)); 
    vBox.add(component);

    return vBox;
}
```

Comment: This works, but is also shifts the entire pane which is added in the tabbed pane, so the effect is still that the top of the pane and the first label are in alignment. I want to only shift the tabbed panes (labels). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I fixed my answer. Try new one.

Comment: This does the opposite of what I want. It does not shift the tab labels, it shifts the panel itself, so the labels end up higher than the panel. i need it the other way around. Sorry to both you with this!